# ¿Como delimitar el área de geocodificación en GMaps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocodificación

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web que tiene integración con google maps, estoy usando la librería GMaps y ya intenté delimitar el área en el mapa de varias formas pero no logro conseguirlo, quisiera saber si es factible delimitar dicha área a solo tres ciudades a través del método geocode o dragend, este es mi código:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#direccion_actual").blur(function(){
        map = new GMaps({
                el: '#map',
                lat:22.2986263,
                lng:-97.8791862,
                zoom: 15,
                bounds: strictBounds,
                types: ['geocode']
            });   

        GMaps.geocode({
            address: $("#direccion_actual").val(),
            callback: function(results, status) {
              if (status == 'OK') {
                map.removeMarkers();
                    var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
                    $("#latitud").val(latlng.lat());
                    $("#longitud").val(latlng.lng());
                    map.setCenter(latlng.lat(), latlng.lng());
                    map.addMarker({
                      lat: latlng.lat(),
                      lng: latlng.lng(),
                      draggable:true,
                      icon: 'templates/img/marker_icon.png',
                      infoWindow: {
                        content: '<p>'+$("#direccion_actual").val()+'</p>'
                      },
                      dragend: function(results){
                            var latitud = results.latLng.lat();
                            var longitud = results.latLng.lng();
                            var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latitud), lng: parseFloat(longitud)};
                            GMaps.geocode({
                                  location: latlng,
                                  callback: function(results, status) {
                                      if (status == 'OK') {
                                        if (results[0]) {
                                          $("#direccion_actual").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                          $("#latitud").val(latitud);
                                          $("#longitud").val(longitud);
                                        } else {
                                          window.alert('No results found');
                                        }
                                      } else {
                                        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                                      }
                                  }
                            });
                        }
                    });
              }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

La pregunta es cómo delimitar la geocodificación de otras áreas, y que sólo permita geocodificar las direcciones si estoy en el área que quiero permitir.

Comment: No se entiende qué quieres hacer. ¿Delimitar el área del mapa significa impedir que se pueda navegar fuera del área? ¿Impedir geocodificación de otras áreas?

Comment: Si es correcto quiero delimitar la geocodificación de otras áreas

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [tour] del sitio y lee cómo [help/dont-ask] para crear una buena pregunta. Me temo que las preguntas este tipo son basadas en opiniones, por favor lee: ¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?

Comment: Ok gracias, si la verdad soy nuevo en este blog y necesitaba saber como poder limitar el área en Gmaps ya que es un proyecto que tengo que entregar, les agradecería mucho su apoyo

Comment: Reformulo mi pregunta: ¿Quieres que el resultado de la geocodificación entregue resultados acotados a tres ciudades en específico?

Comment: Si asi es y una disculpa por la demora me encontraba con mucho trabajo estos dias, si basicamente la idea es delimitar los resultados de busqueda o bien cuando se mueva el marcador de posicion delimitarlo a una cierta zona o en su defecto dejar mover libremente el marker pero validar si la posición actual del marker esta dentro del área permitida